# How to pass powershell runner commandline parameter to teamcity?

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I am trying to pass parameter to powershell runner to teamcity.

Following is my settings.

```
Script : File
Script File : InvokeBuild.ps1
Script Execution Mode: Execute .ps1 script with -File argument
Script arguments" "z:" "Comp1","Comp2"
```

But it fails to execute. What am i missing? Build has no artifacts in teamcity. So I am not able to find the issue via log files

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Does the script run without parameters? It's hard to see in the screenshot, but your arguments seem to have a lot of quotes in them. The args get passed to Powershell directly, as if you had typed them on the command line after the script name. You can look in the build log to see how this is working. (Paste the relevant part of the build log for the failure if you can...)

Comment: Please share the error...